# Função predict no GLMM

Tags: r, glm, lme4

### Editado

Quando utilizamos uma regressão logistica tradicional e fazemos uma predição em R por exemplo:

```
library(dplyr)
n = 300
xx<-c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r5")
xxx<-c("e1","e2","e3")
p=0.3
df1 <- data_frame(
  xx1 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
  xx2 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
  xx3 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
  School = factor(sample(xxx, n,re=TRUE)),
  Rank = factor(sample(xx, n,re=TRUE)),
  yx = as.factor(rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = p))
)
df1
mm<-glm(yx ~ xx1 + xx2 + xx3 + School + Rank,binomial,df1)
n11 = data.frame(School="e3",Rank="r2",xx1=8.58,xx2=8.75,xx3=7.92)

predict(mm, n11, type="response") #No meu caso especifico
```

ou
    predict(mm, n11)

dependendo do que nos interessa, sem problema.

Mas quando trabalhamos com GLMM, por exemplo

```
library(lme4)
mm2 <- glmer(yx ~ xx1 + xx2 + xx3 + Rank +  (Rank | School), data = df1, 
family = "binomial",control = glmerControl(calc.derivs = FALSE))
predict(mm2, n11, type="response") #No meu caso especifico
```

apresenta o erro

```
 Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrastes podem ser aplicados apenas a fatores com 2 ou mais níveis
```

Tentei fazer assim

```
 predict(m2,n11, re.form=(~Rank|School))
```

e apresenta o erro

```
 Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
   no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "glmmadmb"
```

Qual seria a forma correta da predição em R em GLMM?

Comment: Cleber, peço desculpas por ser enxerido, mas eu dei uma olhada no teu histórico aqui no Stack Overflow. Foram seis perguntas feitas a maioria não tem respostas. Eu desconfio que isto aconteça porque teus códigos não são reproduzíveis. [Dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em `R`, de modo que as pessoas que querem te ajudar consigam fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: @MarcusNunesAgradeço a atenção, alterei a pergunta, espero que esteja melhor. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

O problema está na declaração do novo conjunto de dados a ser previsto. Em alguns casos (que infelizmene não sei te dizer exatamente quais são), o pacote `lme4` exige que fatores sejam utilizados para fazer a predição. Por isso, criei um novo `df1` levando isto em conta:

```
n = 300
xx<-c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5")
xxx<-c("e1", "e2", "e3")
p=0.3
School = factor(sample(xxx, n, replace=TRUE), levels=xxx, ordered=FALSE)
Rank = factor(sample(xx, n, replace=TRUE), levels=xx, ordered=TRUE)

df1 <- data_frame(
  xx1 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
  xx2 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
  xx3 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
  School = School,
  Rank = Rank,
  yx = as.factor(rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = p))
)

df1
```

Veja que o meu código está muito parecido com o teu original. Entretanto, obriguei `School` e `Rank` a terem fatores especificados (`xxx` e `xx`, respectivamente), além de determinar que `School` não é ordenado e `Rank` é. Além disso, criei objetos chamados `School` e `Rank` fora de `df1`. Isto será importante no futuro.

Até aqui, não há muita diferença em relação ao que tu fez. Agora, perceba como defini `n11`, o conjunto de dados onde a previsão será feita:

```
mm<-glm(yx ~ xx1 + xx2 + xx3 + School + Rank,binomial,df1)

n11 = data.frame(School=sort(unique(School))[3], 
  Rank=sort(unique(Rank))[2], xx1=8.58, xx2=8.75, xx3=7.92)
```

Note que determinei os valores de `School` e `Rank` baseados nos objetos `School` e `Rank` que criei anteriormente. Assim, `sort(unique(School))[3]` é o terceiro valor de `School`. Uma ideia similar vale para `sort(unique(Rank))[2]`. Agora é só fazer as previsões:

```
predict(mm, n11, type="response")
        1 
0.3715539

library(lme4)
mm2 <- glmer(yx ~ xx1 + xx2 + xx3 + Rank +  (Rank | School), data = df1, 
             family = "binomial",control = glmerControl(calc.derivs = FALSE))

predict(mm2, n11, type="response") #No meu caso especifico
        1 
0.4048813
```

Reconheço que escrever os níveis a serem preditos na forma `School=sort(unique(School))[3]` e `Rank=sort(unique(Rank))[2]`é um pouco feio, mas só sei fazer funcionar desta forma.

Comment: Marcus Nunes, muito obrigado pela sua resposta, queria somente mostrar uma que me foi enviada no stackoverflow em Inglês, que pelos meus testes apresenta o mesmo resultado.   Neste caso pode manter a estrutura conforme eu tinha enviado, mas fazendo igualmente você fez (Que eu tinha errado em nao fazer) que seria incluindo o ordered. Deus te abençoe.                                                            n11 = data.frame(School=factor("e3", levels = levels(df1$School),ordered=FALSE),
Rank=factor("r2", levels = levels(df1$Rank),ordered=TRUE),xx1=8.58,xx2=8.75,xx3=7.92)

Comment: Pelo que vi, ambas as respostas tem o mesmo princípio. A mudança na declaração de `n11` é apenas estética. As duas versões acabam ficando idênticas para o propósito da predição. Que bom que duas pessoas chegaram independentemente ao mesmo resultado e ambos te atendem bem.